# How to get excell range name for HSSFCell apache POI API?

Tags: java, apache-poi, excellibrary

As title, I have a little trouble here.
I can get font from cell

```
HSSFFont font =
    cell.getRow().getSheet().getWorkbook().
    getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
```

But now I need to get range name of it. Actually I need something to anchor and determine key cell and its own value cell.

Is there some method to get range name such as `workBook.getName()` or `.getNameAt()` but how to get **name index** from HSSFCell?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from rich text strings, a cell has only one font assigned,
but it may be referenced by more than one named range.
So you'll need to iterate through the named ranges of the workbook and check if the cell is referenced. For the sake of simplicity, I have iterated over all `area.getAllReferencedCells()` - in case of big ranges you'll need to check if the area `isContiguous()` and if your cell/row-index is inside the cell/row-index of `getFirstCell()` and `getLastCell()` bounding box.

For more info check the [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NamedRanges).

[Or search on stackoverflow ...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapache-poi%5D+range+name)

(in my testcase, a cell(row 4, col 3) was referenced by three different shaped named ranges)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

public class XlsRangeNames {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("src/test/resources/name-range.xls"));

        Cell cell = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(3).getCell(2);

        for (Name n : getNamedRangesForCell(wb, cell)) {
            System.out.println(n.getNameName());
        }
    }

    static List<Name> getNamedRangesForCell(Workbook wb, Cell cell) {
        int col = cell.getColumnIndex();
        int row = cell.getRowIndex();
        String sheetName = cell.getSheet().getSheetName();
        List<Name> result = new ArrayList<Name>();

        for (int i=0; i<wb.getNumberOfNames(); i++) {
            Name name = wb.getNameAt(i);
            if (!sheetName.equals(name.getSheetName())) continue;

            AreaReference area = new AreaReference(name.getRefersToFormula());
            CellReference crList[] = area.getAllReferencedCells();
            for (CellReference cr : crList) {
                if (cr.getCol() == col
                    && cr.getRow() == row) {
                    result.add(name);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```